# In HTML, how to stop propagation of the spacebar activating a container button

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Suppose I have an `<input>` inside a `<button>` like the following.  Doing stopPropagation inside `onclick` stops a click on the text input from actuating the containing button.  But when I press the **spacebar** while inside that text input, **how do I stop that event from propagating** and thus actuating the button?

In other words, I want to type space characters into the text input below freely without getting an alert.  Can this be done?

I thought the answer might be to make `onkeyup` or `oninput` stop propagation, but doing so doesn't change anything.

```html
<button onclick="alert('button activated');">
   Part of label
   <input type="text" 
          onclick="(arguments[0] || window.event).stopPropagation();">
   End of label
</button>
```

Comment: Side note: such structure (nested interactive elements, input inside button) is strongly discouraged and invalid from standards perspective and may have even more unpredictable outcomes that expected.  If possible, consider splitting it to non-nested elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `onkeyup` with `preventDefault` to prevent key release of `space` which triggers that button click.

```html
<button onclick="alert('button activated');">
   Part of label
   <input type="text"
          onkeyup="(arguments[0] || window.event).preventDefault();" 
          onclick="(arguments[0] || window.event).stopPropagation();">
   End of label
</button>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  Do you know why `stopPropagation` onkeyup doesn't work in this case?

Comment: `stopPropagation` is to stop the same event being called. Usually, we use it for `onclick` to prevent the upper `onclick`. We don't have any `onkeyup` on the button, so it's useless in this case. :D @PatrickSzalapski

Comment: Okay, so the button must be listening for some other DOM event if it doesn't listen for a propagated keyup event? Any idea what that other event is?